# 'polar' forms of quaternions

Tags: rotations, quaternions, hopf-fibration

We call a quaternion $q = q_0 + q_1 i + q_2 j +q_3 k$ purely imaginary if $q_0=0$.
Here $q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3$ are real numbers, and $i, j, k$ the three imaginary units.

Is there a reference for the fact that any quaternion $q$ can be written as the product of a purely imaginary one $p$ times a phase $\psi\in (0,2\pi]$,
$$q = p e^{i \psi}$$
or a discussion/proof available?

Comment: Do we have a choice for $i$?  Does it have to be the specific square root of $-1$ we call $i$ or can we use any square root of $-1$ before $\psi$?

Comment: If you need an intuition, you can consider the coefficients of i,j,k on a 3D sphere in polar/spherical coordinates. Q= Re{Q} + R($\theta ,r,\phi$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a $\psi\in [0,2\pi)$ such that $(q_0 + q_1 i)e^{-i \psi}$ is purely imaginary.  Since $(q_2 j + q_3 k)e^{-i \psi}$ is of the form $rj+sk$, it follows that $p=qe^{-i \psi}$ is purely imaginary.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.